# Python multiprocessing SyncManager client and server connection

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I want to use python Multiprocessing SyncManager  to communicate with parent and child processes. In parent process I create manager this way:

```
class JobQueueManager(SyncManager):
pass

JobQueueManager.register('get_job_q', callable=lambda: job_q)
JobQueueManager.register('get_result_q', callable=lambda: result_q)
...
manager = JobQueueManager(address=('127.0.0.1', port), authkey=authkey)
manager.start()
print 'Server started at port %s' % port
return manager
```

And in child:

```
manager = ServerQueueManager(address=(ip, port), authkey=authkey)
manager.connect()
```

But manager.connect() in child hangs when I start it with Subprocess('child.py') function. When I run child process from Linux CLI they are work perfect.

What difference when I run process from CLI, from Subprocess method or with Process(target=f, args=('bob',)) function and when I should use SyncManager?